# How to avoid Skroll.js to create extra space in footer?

Tags: javascript, css

there is something going wrong when I use `var s = skrollr.init({smoothScrolling:true});`... it is creating extra space in my footer. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Here is the page I am working on. It might have more fail yet but it is new and I haven't finish this new design. http://climatizacr.com/2013/index.html

Comment: Please include the unminified skrollr so I can debug this better.

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://climatizacr.com/2013/js/skrollr.js thank you very much!

Comment: http://climatizacr.com/2013/index.html is still pointing to the minified version.

Comment: Hey you're the developer who made Skrollr, it is my a honor!

Comment: Download the latest version, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in skrollr. In your particular case just set the `forceHeight` option to `false`.

I opened an issue on GitHub to not forget about this. https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/216

Comment: Thank you very much Prinzhorn, it worked... I just change `!== false` for `= false` and everything runs great! Thanks again.

Comment: I had the same issue and setting forceHeight to true does indeed work, however I get a "twitching" side-effect when reaching the bottom of the page and trying to continuw scrolling (http://raduluchian.com/).

Comment: var s = skrollr.init({forceHeight: false});

(incase someone doesn't know how to do that)